# Datatable object passed as parameters on button click

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, datatables

I want to pass the datatable object as parameters to controller in post method in laravel. I have tried but it does not work, please help. Below are the code I have tried.

### Datatable Object

```
 Array
 (
 [draw] => 1
 [columns] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [data] => id
                [name] => 
                [searchable] => true
                [orderable] => true
                [search] => Array
                    (
                        [value] => 
                        [regex] => false
                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [data] => name
                [name] => 
                [searchable] => true
                [orderable] => true
                [search] => Array
                    (
                        [value] => 
                        [regex] => false
                    )

            )
    )

[order] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [column] => 0
                [dir] => asc
            )

    )

[start] => 0
[length] => 10
[search] => Array
    (
        [value] => 
        [regex] => false
    )

[_token] => RwkzmLMcy9VW9bzwPN54zv320YsY7Rwbt7sPZCzm
```

)

### Below are the Jquery datatable list works fine

```
var oTable = $('#dataTables-baselineComplete').dataTable({                          
          "processing": true,
          "serverSide": true,     
          "ajax": {
            "url": "{!!url('admin/baselinereport')!!}",
            "type": "POST",
            "data":{"_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}"},
          },
          "columns": [
                { "data": "id" },
                { "data": "name" },                 
          ],

        });
```

I want to pass this datatable object to another route function. Please help

### Html Input

```
<input type="button" name="search" id="search"/>
```

### Jquery

```
$("#search").click(function(){      
 $.ajax({
    url:'{!!url('admin/sample')!!}',
    method:'POST',
    data:{"_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}","datatable_object": oTable},
    success:function(response){
    }
 });
```

});

### Route

```
 Route::post('admin/sample','SampleController@sampleFn');
```

when I click search button - ajax call and post this datatable object as input to that SampleController - sampleFn(). Please help thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`ajax.params()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.params()) to get the data submitted by DataTables to the server in the last Ajax request.

Because you have initialized your table with `dataTable()` instead of `DataTable()`, you have to call this API method as `oTable.api().ajax.params()`.

For example:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'{!!url('admin/sample')!!}',
    method:'POST',
    data:{
        "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
        "datatable_object": oTable.api().ajax.params()
    },
    success:function(response){
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes.. I am got  dataTable Object as params..Thank you So much... Gyrocode.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. The last version uses `table.ajax.params()` without api().